# Timeout Expired during Link server query

Tags: t-sql, triggers, sql-server-2012, query-optimization

I have a SQL Server 2017 database which has 10 tables. Each table is filled by 3rd party application.

When there is any insert/update in any table, a trigger is fired. The trigger updates another table located in remote SQL Server 2017 instance & database (`linkserver`).

That remote database includes only one table which maintains the information of source database (10 tables). So I have 10 `after insert` triggers and 10 `after update` triggers. Each table has about 172 column.

Sometimes, I get an error

> Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding

My `after insert` trigger is:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[AfterINSERTTriggerONE] on [dbo].[ONE]
FOR INSERT AS
INSERT INTO [TargetServer].[TargetDb].[dbo].[DataLogs]( 
                [DeviceId],
                [DateTime],
                [TimeStampUTC],
                [StationIsOpen],
                [PanelIsOpen],
                [PowerIsOscillating], 
                [Heater1_FlameIsOn], 
                [Heater1_Flame2IsOn], 
                [Heater1_WaterLevelSwitch], 
                [Heater2_FlameIsOn], 
                [Heater2_Flame2IsOn], 
                [Heater2_WaterLevelSwitch], 
                [Heater3_FlameIsOn], 
                [Heater3_Flame2IsOn], 
                [Heater3_WaterLevelSwitch], 
                [Heater4_FlameIsOn], 
                [Heater4_Flame2IsOn], 
                [Heater4_WaterLevelSwitch], 
                [Ups_BatteryMode], 
                [Ups_BatteryCharging], 
                [Ups_ShutdownEvent], 
                [Ups_Remote], 
                [Filter1], 
                [Filter2], 
                [Filter3], 
                [AirConditionerIsOn], 
                [R1_P], 
                [R1_T], 
                [R1_Qb], 
                [R1_Qm], 
                [R1_C], 
                [R1_CarbonDioxide], 
                [R1_Nitrogen], 
                [R1_TbX], 
                [R1_PbX], 
                [R1_Methane], 
                [R1_Ethane], 
                [R1_Propane], 
                [R1_iButane], 
                [R1_BatRemain], 
                [R1_Productivity], 
                [R2_P], 
                [R2_T], 
                [R2_Qb], 
                [R2_Qm], 
                [R2_C], 
                [R2_CarbonDioxide], 
                [R2_Nitrogen], 
                [R2_TbX], 
                [R2_PbX], 
                [R2_Methane], 
                [R2_Ethane], 
                [R2_Propane], 
                [R2_iButane], 
                [R2_BatRemain], 
                [R2_Productivity], 
                [R3_P], 
                [R3_T], 
                [R3_Qb], 
                [R3_Qm], 
                [R3_C], 
                [R3_CarbonDioxide], 
                [R3_Nitrogen], 
                [R3_TbX], 
                [R3_PbX], 
                [R3_Methane], 
                [R3_Ethane], 
                [R3_Propane], 
                [R3_iButane], 
                [R3_BatRemain], 
                [R3_Productivity], 
                [R4_P], 
                [R4_T], 
                [R4_Qb], 
                [R4_Qm], 
                [R4_C], 
                [R4_CarbonDioxide], 
                [R4_Nitrogen], 
                [R4_TbX], 
                [R4_PbX], 
                [R4_Methane], 
                [R4_Ethane], 
                [R4_Propane], 
                [R4_iButane], 
                [R4_BatRemain], 
                [R4_Productivity], 
                [Total_Qb], 
                [Total_Qm], 
                [InGasP], 
                [InGasT], 
                [OutGasP], 
                [OutGasT], 
                [AirT], 
                [AirHumadity], 
                [PanelT], 
                [PanelHumadity], 
                [ConexTemperature], 
                [ConexHumadity], 
                [StationCapacity], 
                [Productivity], 
                [Heater1_InGasT], 
                [Heater1_WaterT], 
                [Heater1_OutGasT], 
                [Heater1_WaterLevel], 
                [Heater2_InGasT], 
                [Heater2_WaterT], 
                [Heater2_OutGasT], 
                [Heater2_WaterLevel], 
                [Heater3_InGasT], 
                [Heater3_WaterT], 
                [Heater3_OutGasT], 
                [Heater3_WaterLevel], 
                [Heater4_InGasT], 
                [Heater4_WaterT], 
                [Heater4_OutGasT], 
                [Heater4_WaterLevel], 
                [OdorizerLevel1], 
                [OdorizerLevel2], 
                [Ups_AmbientTemperature], 
                [Ups_BatteryDischargeCurrent], 
                [Ups_BatteryVoltage], 
                [Ups_OutputVoltage], 
                [TBS_OutGasP], 
                [R1_VbT], 
                [R1_Vb], 
                [R1_Vbd], 
                [R1_VmT], 
                [R1_Vm], 
                [R1_Vmd], 
                [R1_Vb_PrevDay], 
                [R1_Vm_PrevDay], 
                [R2_VbT], 
                [R2_Vb], 
                [R2_Vbd], 
                [R2_VmT], 
                [R2_Vm], 
                [R2_Vmd], 
                [R2_Vb_PrevDay], 
                [R2_Vm_PrevDay], 
                [R3_VbT], 
                [R3_Vb], 
                [R3_Vbd], 
                [R3_VmT], 
                [R3_Vm], 
                [R3_Vmd], 
                [R3_Vb_PrevDay], 
                [R3_Vm_PrevDay], 
                [R4_VbT], 
                [R4_Vb], 
                [R4_Vbd], 
                [R4_VmT], 
                [R4_Vm], 
                [R4_Vmd], 
                [R4_Vb_PrevDay], 
                [R4_Vm_PrevDay],
                [Total_Vb_PrevDay] 
        ) 
     select
        StationName,
        Time_Stamp,
        Utc,
        StationIsOpen,
        PanelIsOpen,
        PowerIsOscillating,
        Heater1_FlameIsOn,
        Heater1_Flame2IsOn,
        Heater1_WaterLevelSwitch,
        Heater2_FlameIsOn,
        Heater2_Flame2IsOn,
        Heater2_WaterLevelSwitch,
        Heater3_FlameIsOn,
        Heater3_Flame2IsOn,
        Heater3_WaterLevelSwitch,
        Heater4_FlameIsOn,
        Heater4_Flame2IsOn,
        Heater4_WaterLevelSwitch,
        Ups_BatteryMode,
        Ups_BatteryCharging,
        Ups_ShutdownEvent,
        Ups_Remote,
        Filter1,
        Filter2,
        Filter3,
        AirConditionerIsOn,
        R1_P,
        R1_T,
        R1_Qb,
        R1_Qm,
        R1_C,
        R1_CarbonDioxide,
        R1_Nitrogen,
        R1_TbX,
        R1_PbX,
        R1_Methane,
        R1_Ethane,
        R1_Propane,
        R1_iButane,
        R1_BatRemain,
        R1_Productivity,
        R2_P,
        R2_T,
        R2_Qb,
        R2_Qm,
        R2_C,
        R2_CarbonDioxide,
        R2_Nitrogen,
        R2_TbX,
        R2_PbX,
        R2_Methane,
        R2_Ethane,
        R2_Propane,
        R2_iButane,
        R2_BatRemain,
        R2_Productivity,
        R3_P,
        R3_T,
        R3_Qb,
        R3_Qm,
        R3_C,
        R3_CarbonDioxide,
        R3_Nitrogen,
        R3_TbX,
        R3_PbX,
        R3_Methane,
        R3_Ethane,
        R3_Propane,
        R3_iButane,
        R3_BatRemain,
        R3_Productivity,
        R4_P,
        R4_T,
        R4_Qb,
        R4_Qm,
        R4_C,
        R4_CarbonDioxide,
        R4_Nitrogen,
        R4_TbX,
        R4_PbX,
        R4_Methane,
        R4_Ethane,
        R4_Propane,
        R4_iButane,
        R4_BatRemain,
        R4_Productivity,
        Total_Qb,
        Total_Qm,
        InGasP,
        InGasT,
        OutGasP,
        OutGasT,
        AirT,
        AirHumadity,
        PanelT,
        PanelHumadity,
        ConexTemperature,
        ConexHumadity,
        StationCapacity,
        Productivity,
        Heater1_InGasT,
        Heater1_WaterT,
        Heater1_OutGasT,
        Heater1_WaterLevel,
        Heater2_InGasT,
        Heater2_WaterT,
        Heater2_OutGasT,
        Heater2_WaterLevel,
        Heater3_InGasT,
        Heater3_WaterT,
        Heater3_OutGasT,
        Heater3_WaterLevel,
        Heater4_InGasT,
        Heater4_WaterT,
        Heater4_OutGasT,
        Heater4_WaterLevel,
        OdorizerLevel1,
        OdorizerLevel2,
        Ups_AmbientTemperature,
        Ups_BatteryDischargeCurrent,
        Ups_BatteryVoltage,
        Ups_OutputVoltage,
        TBS_OutGasP,
        R1_VbT,
        R1_Vb,
        R1_Vbd,
        R1_VmT,
        R1_Vm,
        R1_Vmd,
        R1_Vb_PrevDay,
        R1_Vm_PrevDay,
        R2_VbT,
        R2_Vb,
        R2_Vbd,
        R2_VmT,
        R2_Vm,
        R2_Vmd,
        R2_Vb_PrevDay,
        R2_Vm_PrevDay,
        R3_VbT,
        R3_Vb,
        R3_Vbd,
        R3_VmT,
        R3_Vm,
        R3_Vmd,
        R3_Vb_PrevDay,
        R3_Vm_PrevDay,
        R4_VbT,
        R4_Vb,
        R4_Vbd,
        R4_VmT,
        R4_Vm,
        R4_Vmd,
        R4_Vb_PrevDay,
        R4_Vm_PrevDay,
        Total_Vb_PrevDay

    from inserted;
PRINT 'We Successfully Fired the AFTER INSERT Trigger for Table [ONE] in SQL Server.'
```

and AfterUpdate:

```
    ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[AfterUpdateTriggerONE] ON [dbo].[ONE]
    AFTER UPDATE 
    AS
    if (UPDATE (StationIsOpen))   
                BEGIN 
                UPDATE [TargetServer].[TargetDBDb].[dbo].[DataLogs]
                SET    Trg.StationIsOpen = ins.StationIsOpen , Trg.Updated = 1
                FROM   [TargetServer].[TargetDBDb].[dbo].[DataLogs] Trg
                       JOIN inserted ins
                         ON Trg.[DateTime] = ins.[Time_Stamp] AND
                            Trg.[DeviceId] = ins.[StationName]
                END
    
    if (UPDATE (PanelIsOpen))   
                BEGIN 
                UPDATE [TargetServer].[TargetDBDb].[dbo].[DataLogs]
                SET    Trg.PanelIsOpen = ins.PanelIsOpen , Trg.Updated = 1
                FROM   [TargetServer].[TargetDBDb].[dbo].[DataLogs] Trg
                       JOIN inserted ins
                         ON Trg.[DateTime] = ins.[Time_Stamp] AND
                            Trg.[DeviceId] = ins.[StationName]
                END
.
.
. 
and all other 170 columns
```

Comment: WARNING, your trigger is **fatally** flawed. `inserted` contains 1 **or more** rows, and your trigger *assumes* it will only ever contain **one**. You *need* to fix that.

Comment: Also, I would strongly suggest not doing such an operation in a `TRIGGER`. A Trigger should have an **minimal** impact as possible, and running queries against a remote server can often not be very minimal. Have an automated task migrate data, or (possibly better) use something like replication. This is very likely an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: Also, your table `dbo.ONE` appears to be denormalised, with column names like `Heater1_InGasT`,`Heater2_InGasT, `Heater3_InGasT`, etc

Comment: @Lamu Thank you for your response. i am not the admin of Target Database i just have insert and update access to remote Database. can i create merge replication between two tables  which have different column names instead of using triggers?

Comment: No, you wouldn't be able to, so i would suggest an automated process that uses a "pooling" table to do the "migration".

Comment: @Lamu would you please more explain? which automated process? i have tried MERGE for update and insert but it does not work for Remote database so i used after insert and update trigger.. my after insert trigger works sometimes but sometimes i get Timeout error.  can i optimize my triggers or i should not use this method at all (excuse my english ;) )

Comment: *"which automated process?"* One *you* create and run via Agent. *"or i should not use this method at all "* That is exactly what I say in my second comment: "A Trigger should have an minimal impact as possible, and running queries against a remote server can often not be very minimal"

Comment: If nothing else, changing `[AfterINSERTTriggerONE]` to `INSERT INTO [Target].[TargetDb].[dbo].[DataLogs]( ... ) from select ... from inserted;` handles multiple rows, is easier to maintain and might perform better than running 172 `select`s on `inserted`.

Comment: @HABO Thank you .. i changed my query to this form, what about update trigger any suggestion for tuning?

Comment: `Update()` returns `true` if a column is _specified_ in an `update`, even if the value isn't changed. Ordinarily that wouldn't matter, but since you're reaching out to remote server you want to avoid unnecessary work. You _might_ want to use `if exists ( select 42 from Inserted as I inner join Deleted as D on D.Id = I.Id and D.StationIsOpen != I.StationIsOpen )` (`Id`?) (and similarly for `PanelIsOpen`) to check for values that have changed. Notes: 1) The logic is more complicated if the column is nullable. B) You can add it to the `update`, but `Updated` won't be set for unchanged rows.

Comment: @HABO actually i need something like as MERGE or Replication (If there is a row in remote Database, it should be updated and if it does not exist, it should be inserted) i cant use merge because  target is in remote server and i cant use replication because tables have different column names. so i used after insert and after update triger. after insert  works properly but when i enable after update i get abort transaction error. 1)what is 42 in your code? 2) you mean i use if exist(..) instead of  if (UPDATE (StationIsOpen)) ?

Comment: i) [42](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker's_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Why_the_number_42?) is the _select list_ for the `select` statement in the `exists` subquery. There has to be something there, but it is ignored. You could replace it with `NULL`, `0`, `*` or `1 / 0` and get the same result. Really. b) Yes, `if exists ( ... )` instead of `if Update(...)`. That will skip the `update` if none of the values were changed. Adding `where exists ( ... )` to the `update` statement will cause it to only update rows (and `Updated`) where the value of the column was changed.

Comment: @HABO you're a HERO :D